# Proof of an infinite sum involving cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have a homework problem that requires proving the Poisson formula from the Jensen-Poisson formula.  I have all steps of the problem complete except for proving the identity (for $r < 1$) $$1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2r^n \cos (n(\phi - \theta)) = \frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2 - 2r \cos (\phi-\theta)},$$
on which I'm not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identity

> $$ \cos(t) = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} $$

and the geometric series

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^k = \frac{1}{1-t}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Use $r^n \cos(n\theta) = \text{Re}((r e^{i\theta})^n)$.  Then you have the real part of a geometric series.